# chrome.scripting.executeScript - Unexpected property: 'arguments'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use chrome.scripting.executeScript for a chrome extension I'm building in ManifestV3 and following the Google documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) (see image below):

[image]

I have added an 'arguments' property to pass in the title of the current tab to my function. However, I am getting the following error message:

`TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'injection': Unexpected property: 'arguments'.`

Here is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
  let tab = tabs[0];
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: myFunction,
      arguments: [tab.title],
    },
    (injectionResults) => displaySearch(injectionResults[0].result)
  );
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help [ScriptInjection](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection)

Comment: https://crbug.com/1166720, it's not yet implemented.

Comment: Found any workaround to pass arguments?

Comment: not arguments , it's args like `args: [param1, param2, param3]`.

Answer (score 7):

The property name being used is incorrect. The new API uses the property "args".
For example:

```
function greet(greeting) {
   console.log(`${greeting}, World!`);
}

chrome.scripting.executeScript({
     target: {tabId: tab.id},
     function: greet,
     args: ['Hello']
});

Output: Hello, World!
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection).

Comment: They changed it recently. At the time this was posted, Google hadn't implemented it yet and the documentation was unclear.

Comment: I agree, [Omer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15549903/omer)

Answer (score 4):

There is a workaround for this that you can use until they implement the feature using [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/). What you need to do is first save the argument with `chrome.storage.sync.set()`, then retrieve it inside the function you're injecting using `chrome.storage.sync.get()`.

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({ myVariable: valueOfVariable });

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
  let tab = tabs[0];
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: myFunction,
    }
  );
});

function myFunction() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(["myVariable"], ({ myVariable }) => {
    // Do stuff
  });
}
```